# Ruby on Rail 5.2 Can't start server. Lots of errors I don't understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working my way through a RoR tutorial. All was well until yesterday when I came across a bunch or errors that I can't understand.  It looks like an openssl issue, but what I've read of that involves stuff I'm not using. I didn't add or update any gems. In fact, git shows no changes since my last commit which was working prior to yesterday. Any thoughts? What could have changed from one day to the next. I think the only thing I did was update postgresql using Homebrew. Might that have had some negative   Thanks.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/md5.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/md5.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/md5.bundle
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.54.0/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.54.0/lib/rubocop.rb:613:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.54.0/lib/rubocop.rb:613:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.54.0/bin/rubocop:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/rubocop:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rubocop:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` before running the server?

Comment: you are using encryption md5, and it is saying that you need openssl for it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to install openssl

in macOS you can do it with `brew install openssl` and than install your gems again with `brew install --force` to make sure that the correct library path was used during the compilation

in case it won't work try installing openssl version 1.0 (since that's the version mention in the stacktrace) with `brew install openssl@1.0` and then reinstalling your gems again

did you upgrade your OS? or did it happen by itself maybe?